# What is the meaning of Föhn in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The sentence:

> Der Föhn, der andernorts wie ein Wasserfall die Berge hinabdonnert und orkanartig durch die Täler braust, ...

The dictionary tells me Föhn means blow dryer, but the sentence suggests that Föhn can also mean wind or gust or something of that nature. Is it safe to make that assumption or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Föhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foehn_wind) in your case is a dry and warm, often gusty strong downslope wind in the Alps.

It's a weather phenomenon that is observed in mountainous area and possibly has its name from Favonius, the Roman personification of a favourable wind.

Comment: The hairdryer is named after this warm wind. It was a brandname of Electrolux and originally was written without h (»Fön«), a variation was »Foen«. Before the orthographic reform of 1996 *Fön* was the correct spelling for the hairdryer, while the wind always was written with h (»Föhn«). After 1996 only *Föhn* is correct for both, the wind and the hairdryer.

Comment: @Hubert  Or perhaps more neutrally expressed: "after 1996 only Föhn is considered correct by those who adhere to the new rules of orthography issued then for the use in schools and public administration"?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Are you sure? https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Foen suggests that Fön is ok as well.

Comment: @glglgl: Yes, I am sure, and Duden agrees with me. The entry you found is explicitly marked with the sign ® which means, that this entry is about a **R**egistered trademark, i.e. this entry is about the Hairdryer by Electrolux. In the section *Bedeutung* is a link to *Föhn (2).* If you follow this link and read entry 2, you can read *"elektrisches Gerät zum Trocknen des Haars".* So, all in all Duden says: You can use *Fön* and *Föhn* for the hairdryer, but the wind is only *Föhn.* And this is exactly what I said 2 years ago.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I read your sentence from 2017 as "only Föhn is correct for both" while Duden says "You can use Fön and Föhn for the hairdryer". So the latter seems to apply.

Comment: @glglgl: No. The statement *"After 1996 only Föhn is correct for both"* means, that from the two words (*Fön, Föhn*) only *Föhn* can be used for the hairdryer and the wind, while this is not allowed for *Fön.* In other words: *Fön* can not be used for both, but only for a hairdryer (to be captious: I only can be used for a hairdryer made by Electrolux).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Then I got you wrong. Thanks for the clarification (and sorry for excavating this old stuff).